# How do I resolve the Can't contact LDAP server issue in Laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

I have a Laravel 8 installation using LDAP Authentication. I'm running it locally using artisan serve/xampp. I am getting the 'can't contact ldap server' error when attempting to log in. The error occurs on adldap2\src\Auth\Guard.php:

```
if (@$this->connection->bind($username, $password) === true) {....
```

All settings are the same and working on a colleagues computer, so assume this is a local issue? I've ensured the ldap extension is in my php.ini file. Please could someone advise what else I need to check? I feel it's something to do with my xampp settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was to connect to the vpn